# how to use dict item inside that dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my code,

```
class Dialog:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.geometry = {
            'width': kwargs['width'] if 'width' in kwargs else 300,
            'height': kwargs['width'] if 'height' in kwargs else 170,
            'x': self.geometry['width'] / 2),
            'y': self.geometry['height'] / 2)
        }
```

I wanna use my `self.geometry` values inside creating new item

But i get this error

```
AttributeError: 'Dialog' object has no attribute 'geometry'
```

Comment: P.S, look at [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) for nicer defaults

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class Dialog:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.geometry = {
            'width': kwargs['width'] if 'width' in kwargs else 300,
            'height': kwargs['width'] if 'height' in kwargs else 170
        }
        self.geometry['x']: self.geometry['width'] / 2
        self.geometry['y']: self.geometry['height'] / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the variable before you can add things:

```
class Dialog:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.geometry = {
            'width': kwargs['width'] if 'width' in kwargs else 300,
            'height': kwargs['width'] if 'height' in kwargs else 170}
        self.geometry['x'] = self.geometry['width'] / 2
        self.geometry['y'] = self.geometry['height'] / 2
```